# How to "rename" a file in Git after already having moved it with bash/mv

Tags: git

I often rename files with the `mv` system command, forgetting to use `git mv` in order to keep the file history:

```
~/gitproj $ mv myfile.foo newname.foo
```

When I realize it before a commit, the only way I know to fix it is to do the following:

```
~/gitproj $ mv newname.foo myfile.foo        # Coming back to the old name
~/gitproj $ git mv myfile.foo newname.foo    # Moving forth again, but with git
```

Is there a better way to do it, like only giving to `git` the info that the file was moved?

It would be something like that:

```
~/gitproj $ git mv --cached myfile.foo newname.foo   # a pseudo git command
```

#### Edit:

As AndreasGrapentin wrote:

```
git add .
```

let git (auto)detect all the files which were renamed, even if they were modified. But this command adds the whole directory to the index...

Is there a way, even in a lower level, to change this info only for one file?

Comment: `git add .` will notice when a file was moved (almost) always.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: there are many modifications in my file, and git doesn't detect the move with `git add`

Comment: in that case, the modifications should have been a separate commit to the move. In my experience, a `git mv` can only do so much when the file in question has been edited massively (YMMV)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: Oh, sorry you're right : indeed, `git add .` detects the move

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: but all files in the directory are added, and that's not what I would like : I just want to inform git that **one** file had moved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the effect of `git mv` is nothing more or less than the sequence

```
mv myfile.foo newname.foo
git rm --cached myfile.foo
git add newname.foo
```

anyway, you can simply supply the remaining two operations

```
git rm --cached myfile.foo
git add newname.foo
```

to finish the move. However, that does not save you a single command from your move-back-then-git-move workaround.

Afaik, these two commands cannot be bundled via a git alias: You need to supply two names to two different commands, and that is incompatible with alias substitution. So, if you absolutely want to be able to do this with a single command, you either need to write a shell script or function. With a shell script, you can then alias it in your `~/.gitconfig` if you absolutely want to call it as a git command, but I really wouldn't bother if I were you.

Comment: I don't need a single command. It's perfect like that, thanks

Comment: There's a trick for making such aliases: `[alias] foo = '!f() { ...; } f'`. Inside shell function `f` you can test `$#`, loop, etc. (But I wouldn't bother here either :-) )

Comment: on mercurial `hg mv --after` is so convenient ! I miss it :D